# Make Utility creates object files, although I haven't defined their targets in the makefile

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have written a simple makefile for compiling my C programs. I have a **main.c** and **functions.c** file.
My makefile looks like this:

```
main : main.o functions.o
    gcc main.o functions.o -o main

clean : 
    rm *.o main
```

As you can see I haven't defined targets for main.o and functions.o, but still the executable file is generated when I run **make**.

Can you tell me why make utility didn't produce an error ?

Comment: try runing ```make -p``` ,  look for output like ```main.o: main.c``` and ```#  Implicit rule search has been done.``` and ```# Not a target: functions.c```  for my environment I see this error ```error: no such file or directory: 'functions.o'``` but because there is an implicit rule for ```main.o: main.c``` the implicit rule knows how to create ```main.o```, maybe this environment has implicit rules for ```.c``` to ```.o``` ?

Comment: [Maybe this description of built in make rules for compiling *.o from *.c helps](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU Make has a [catalog of built-in rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) to build certain files from their dependencies.  In this case, your dependencies main.o and functions.o are missing and it figures from the pattern rules that it build those from .c files.  There is also a rule for linking so you should be able to just specify:

```
.PHONY: clean

main: main.o functions.o

clean: 
    rm -f *.o main
```

Part of the value of make is [standard targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html), so you should consider adding the ones that are relevant for your project.